# NSString find and replace html tags attgibutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

I have pretty simple `NSString`

f.e

```
<scirpt attribute_1="x" attribute2="x" attribute3="x" ... attributeX="x"/>
```

I need to find specific parameter, let's say `attribute2` and replace it's value,
I know the exact name of parameter f.e `attribute2` but I don't know anything about it's value.

I guess it can be easily done by regexp, but I quite newbie on it.

In conclusion: I want to grab

```
attribute2="xxxx...xxx"
```

from incoming string

**Note:** I don't want to use some 3rd party libs to achieve that (it's temporary hack)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked it together with some string operations:

```
NSDictionary* valuesToReplace = @{@"attribute_1" : @"newValue1"};
NSString* sourceHtml = @"<scirpt attribute_1=\"x\" attribute2=\"x\" attribute3=\"x\" attributeX=\"x\" />";
NSArray* attributes = [sourceHtml componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for (NSString* pair in attributes)
{
    NSArray* attributeValue = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    if([attributeValue count] > 1) //to skip first "script" element
    {
        NSString* attr = [attributeValue firstObject]; //get attribute name

        if([valuesToReplace objectForKey:attr]) //check if should be replaced
        {
            NSString* newPair = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=\"%@\"", attr, [valuesToReplace objectForKey:attr]]; //create new string for that attribute
            sourceHtml = [sourceHtml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:pair withString:newPair]; //replace it in sourceHtml
        }
    }
}
```

It's really only when you want to hack it and you know the format :) Shoot a question if you have any.

Comment: got it, actually I was on that way, but you made it be faster, thx

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.. https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

import "NSString+HTML.h" along with dependencies
And write like this...

```
simpletxt.text = [YourHTMLString stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
```